# undefined local variable or method `message' (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber

I am trying to learn Rspec-Cucumber tutorial by referring to "The Pragmatic Programmers - The Rspec Book". I am on the 4th chapter and seems to be stuck with an error and not able to move forward.I have followed exactly as per the tutorial but it is showing the below error (`in line : output.messages.should include(message)`) when I try to run cucumber feature in my console.

```
undefined local variable or method `message' for #<Object:0x9c0c05c> (NameError)
```

My codebreaker_steps.rb file is as follows.

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
output.messages.should include(message)
end

class Output
    def messages
    @messages ||= []
    end

    def puts(message)
    messages << message
    end
end

    def output
    @output ||= Output.new
    end
```

Comment: Where do you think `message` (the argument you've passed to `include`) is defined?

Answer (score 1):

It would be very helpful to you if you take time to familiarize yourself with the basics of ruby.  To answer your question, you should change the step definition like this

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  output.messages.should include(arg1)
end
```

or like this

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |message|
  output.messages.should include(message)
end
```